# pandas: cannot coerce a Timestamp with a tz on a naive Block

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a very simple operation. I just need to set the value of a cell to be time zone aware timestamp. yet my index would be a rather complex string. Explicitly, it is:

```
 df_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
 str_of_contract_tuple_now = "('ZT', 'FUT', 'ECBOT', 'USD', '20180329', 0.0)"
```

By trying to do:

```
    df_tmp[str_of_contract_tuple_now,"time"] = pd.Timestamp.now("EST5EDT)
```

I got the error:

> TypeError: cannot coerce a Timestamp with a tz on a naive Block

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: I can reproduce, but only on an older version.  Try on pandas 0.21.0+